# Static file not found

Tags: python, node.js, django, saleor

I am using [Saleor](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor) and I am trying to add a new static folder called fonts into the static folder. When I add a file to static/images I can reference the file, but if I create a folder called fonts: static/fonts and add the same file to it, the file is not found in the browser.

I have tried "npm run build-assets" and cleared Cached images and files in the browser but the font file is still not found.

Works:

```
<link href="{% static 'images/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Does not work:

```
<link href="{% static 'fonts/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Any idea how to make new folders load into static files?
BTW I feel like this must be a nodejs thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, i really didn't know this package but it's look like you have to add your folder to STATICFILES_DIRS :

https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/221b101a4517d9e4b409523fcb81649be368af95/saleor/settings.py#L81

So it should look like that i think :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ('assets', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'saleor', 'static', 'assets')),
    ('images', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'saleor', 'static', 'images')),
    ('dashboard', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'saleor', 'static', 'dashboard')),
    ('fonts' os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'saleor', 'static', 'fonts'))
]
```

Have fun !